# Is this an equivalent definition of limits in perfect Hausdorff spaces?

Tags: general-topology, limits

The normal definition of limit $f(x)\to L\mbox{ when } x\to a$ is that for every (open) neighborhood $U$ of $L$ theres a punctured (open) neighborhood $V$ of $a$ such that $f(V)\subseteq U$.

Now I've considered a similar construct that results in a set:

$${\lim_{x\to a}}^*f(x) = \bigcap \overline{f(V)}$$

Where $V$ are punctured (open) neighborhoods of $a$. The idea is to produce something like the range of the function in the vincinity of $a$.

Now the question is how this relates to the definition of limits.

What I think I've found is that (if there's no isolated points) if there is a unique limit then $\lim^*_{x\to a} f(x)=\{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\}$. The proof for that relies on that $\lim_{x\to a}\in \overline{f(V)}$ for every punctured neighborhood of $a$. Otherwise we would be able to construct another disjoint neighborhood $W$ of $a$ which would mean that the intersection of $V\cup\{a\}$ and $W\cup\{a\}$ would only contain $a$ and still being open.

I think similar can be said if there exists (unique) restricted limits (eg onesided limits) that $\lim^*{x\to a}f(x)$ would contain precisely those.

Now I hope that if it's a perfect Hausdorff space (ie with no isolated points) it would be true that if $\lim^*_{x\to a}$ contains precisely one element it would imple that the limit exists and $\lim_{x\to a}$ is that element. Is that true? Or is there a counter example disproving this?

Comment: "open points" are usually called "isolated points". A space (Hausdorff or otherwise) without isolated points is called "dense in itself" (d.i.i.) or "perfect" (though the latter is a bit ambiguous, I think).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank's for the terminology, I've changed it to "isolated points", but I think I will be explicit to call the space "without isolated point" instead of "perfect" (due to ambiguity) or "dense in itself" (for gramatical reason).

Comment: The term "perfect" is the most common. Sometimes it includes being closed (perfect subsets e.g.), sometimes not. I think saying "perfect Hausdorff spaces" would do (explaining your terms once).

Comment: I think you may have surprises if the space is Hausdorff but not regular or even if it is not Urysohn. A space is regular iff   for any nbhd $U$ of $p$  there is a nbhd $U'$ (of $p$) with $\overline  {U'}\subset U.$  A space is Urysohn iff any 2 points have nbhds whose closures are disjoint.

Comment: Your ${\lim\limits_{x\to a}}^{\ast} f(x)$ is precisely the set of adherent points of the filter $f(\mathscr{V}^{\ast}(a))$, where $\mathscr{V}^{\ast}(a)$ is the filter of punctured neighbourhoods of $a$ (since $a$ isn't isolated, that is a filter). $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists if and only if that filter is convergent. But a filter having only one adherent point doesn't imply that it's convergent, consider the filter generated by the sequence $a_n = n^{(-1)^n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of counterexamples. Let $(X,\tau)$ be any Hausdorff space, $\sigma$ be any topology strictly stronger than $\tau$, and $f:(X,\sigma)\to (X,\tau)$ be the identity map. Indeed, since the map $f$ is not continuous, then there exists a point $x\in X$ and a neighborhood $x\in V\in\sigma$ such that $U=f(U)\not\subset V$ for any neighborhood $x\in U\in\sigma$. From the other side, by the Hausdorffness of the space $(X,\tau)$ we have $\{y\}=\bigcap_{y\in U\in\tau}\overline{U}^\tau\supset\bigcap_{y\in U\in\tau}\overline{f(U)}^\sigma=\{y\}$ for any point $y\in X$.

PS. The answer should be positive when $f$ maps into a compact space.